# Elasticsearch removal of multiple mapping type causing too many fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, lucene

I am making a transition of `Elasticsearch` from `version 5.6` to `6.7`. In `6.x` they said `multiple types` should be brought under `one type`

When brought under one `type`, there are a lot of fields in that new `type`. Lets say in version `5.6`, there were types `A`, `B` and `C`. Each of them had 10 `fields`. So each `document` stored in those `types`, had 10 `fields`.

But in `6.x`, as `A`, `B` and `C` are brought under single `type` `D`, `D` has 30 `fields`. And if we store a `document` of `type` `A` in `D`, 10 fields are used and 20 `fields` (related to `B` and `D`) do not have values. Isn't it a waste? or a bad design?

So I am just finding if there is any way to improve this design. Thanks in advance.

FOOT NOTE: Current version has parent-child relationship that needs to be kept in the in `6.7` too. (not much of a problem, can be done using `join type`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply migrate each type to its own dedicated index, that's the way to go to prevent sparsity.

The only reason to keep several types inside the same index (with a discriminating `type` field) is when they all share a common set of fields, otherwise, each type should go inside its own index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use different indexes, then how can I keep the parent child relationship?

Comment: The first question to ask yourself is whether you think that the parent-child relationship is the way to go. Have you thought about denormalization?